# Making sure resource is owned by tenant in a multi-tenant system in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multi-tenant

I'm trying to create a multi-tenant system and so far, in terms of saving everything is working fine. But earlier, I stumbled upon a problem, I have this service:

```
public interface EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    private IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository= employeeRepository;
    }

    public Employee GetById(int employeeId)
    {
        return _employeeRepository.GetById(employeeId);
    }
}
```

So this service is called from a MVC Controller to retrieve the employee with the Id. The problem is I want to be able to check if the employeeId being passed during the call is owned by the tenant that's calling it, or else he can put any Id in it and retrieve anyone.

The easiest solution I can think of is changing the signature to include the tenantId:

```
public Employee GetById(int tenantId, int employeeId)
```

But I was thinking if there are better ways. I feel that a GetById method should only have 1 parameter. Maybe I am overthinking it, I am not sure.

Another way I can think if is for EmployeeService to have a member TenantId that when it is instantiated, the TenantId is populated and used before the call to GetById to check if it owns the employeeId being retrieved. But I can't make this work because EmployeeService is created during Startup in ConfigureService and I will only know the TenantId once someone has successfully logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter tenantId inside your DBContext dynamically. There is a useful post here.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/02/09/row-level-security-in-entityframework-6-ef6/

You can create an interface like ITenantEntity and it can implemented to other entities which have TenantId.

```
public interface ITenantEntity
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

In your DbContext level, you determine the entities which have tenancy by using `ITenantFilter` and you can filter them dynamically.

Also, you shouldn't pass TenantId filter to methods manually because it is difficult to manage. You can store the TenantId as **ClaimsPrincipal**. You should set the TenantId after user authentication and you can get TenantId from as claim for every request dynamically. 
And we are using same method to manage multi-tenancy in our projects. Actually, it is a perfect solution.